# google ads CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT don't allow to remove first row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-ads-api

I have encounter a problem with the google ads report and I have no clue how to fix it... I use the following code to extract the data from google ads via API call

```
import sys
from googleads import adwords
import pandas as pd
import pandas as np
import io

output = io.StringIO()
def main(client):
  # Initialize appropriate service.
  report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201809')

  # Create report query.
  report_query = (adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()
                  .Select('CampaignId', 'AdGroupId', 'Id', 'Criteria',
                          'CriteriaType', 'FinalUrls', 'Impressions', 'Clicks',
                          'Cost')
                  .From('CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                  .Where('Status').In('ENABLED', 'PAUSED')
                  .During('LAST_7_DAYS')
                  .Build())

  # You can provide a file object to write the output to. For this
  # demonstration we use sys.stdout to write the report to the screen.
  report_downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(
      report_query, 'CSV', output, skip_report_header=False,
      skip_column_header=False, skip_report_summary=False,
      include_zero_impressions=True)
  output.seek(0)
  df = pd.read_csv(output)
  df = df.to_csv('results.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Initialize client object.
  adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()

  main(adwords_client)
```

the code works as expected and pulls the data and save it in a CSV file, however, when I access the columns it prints just one column 'CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT (Nov 5, 2019-Nov 11, 2019)' when I open the csv file looks like this

[result.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odOxh.png)

I have tried to drop the first row with df.drop(df.index[0]) to access the rest of the data however nothing seems to be working. is there any way I can remove the first row or change to use the second row as the columns names which is the result I expected.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to eliminate the header there with the following download request:

```
report_downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(
    report_query, 'CSV', output, skip_report_header=True,
    skip_column_header=False, skip_report_summary=True, 
    include_zero_impressions=True
)
```

I think if you include `skip_report_header=True, skip_report_summary=True` you'll get what you want.

Comment: outstanding exactly what I was looking for... thanks a lot...